# Write to %temp% with python?

Tags: io, path, relative-path, python-3.3, temp

I have a small program that works fine on my PC but I want to make it portable. What it does is download an image from the internet, set as desktop background, wait one minute and update the image. I know that I cannot write directly to folders like appdata, as I do not know the username of the person using the computer. I need to save the downloaded image somewhere, so I would save it in the windows `Temp` folder.

Some options I think would be to (However I don't know how to do this in python)

- Use something like `%temp%` to access the folder.
- Find out the username of the person running the program and insert into path
- Use a variable for the username.
- Use relative paths

I would like to try and not have to use another module not by default included in Python 3, as I want to cx_freeze it later on.

```
import pythoncom
from urllib import request
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
from time import sleep

def get_image():
    f = open('C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\Python\\bg\\bg.jpg', 'wb') #Open old image
    f.write(request.urlopen('blalbla.com/foo/img.jpg').read()) #Get new image and write
    f.close()

pathtoimg = 'C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\Python\\bg\\bg.jpg'

count = 0
while 1:
    get_image()
    iad = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_ActiveDesktop, None,
          pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, shell.IID_IActiveDesktop)
    iad.SetWallpaper(pathtoimg, 0)
    iad.ApplyChanges(shellcon.AD_APPLY_ALL)
    count += 1
    print(count)
    sleep(60)
```

Comment: FOUND AN ANSWER! Will post as soon as it lets me answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to locate Temp:

```
import os

mytmpdir = os.environ['TEMP'] #Must be uppercase
```